# How to redirect a route prefix to another route in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, apache, .htaccess

I am using laravel 5.7. Please see my code:

**web.php**

```
Route::prefix('admin')->group(function () {
        Route::get('/', function () {
           return redirect()->route('admin.check');
       });
Route::get('/check-auth', 'Admin\AdminController@checkAuth')->name('admin.check');
});
```

**`AdminController::checkAuth()`**

```
public function checkAuth()
    {
        if(true == Auth::guard('admin')->user()){
            return redirect()->route('cs.dashboard');
        } else{
            return redirect()->route('admin.login');
        }
    }
```

I have created a group of routes with prefix `admin`.

What I need is, when I use url `localhost:8000/admin` then it should check Auth of admin user, if user is logged in then it should show admin dashboard otherwise redirect him to admin login page : `localhost:8000/admin/login` but the issue over here is I am getting apache error which reads:

```
Not Found
The requested resource /admin was not found on this server.
```

I also tried using htaccess file placing it in `root/public/admin` location, it somewhat solved my issue but I have to use this url.

```
localhost:8000/index.php/admin
```

and I dont need index.php in my url.

This is what my .htaccess file looks:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews -Indexes
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
    RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Please help me to resolve it.

Comment: You can use [middleware](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/middleware)  to check if the user is admin or not.

Comment: I am using this middleware for my other routes but what if someone use url till only  admin, which should be in my closure for that route.

Comment: What about creating a new middleware like `RedirectIfNotAdmin` that enclose your admin routes and that check if the user is admin or not?

Comment: What OS are you using?

Comment: @Laerte I am using Ubuntu 18.04

Comment: Open `/etc/apache2/mods-enabled/dir.conf` and check if `DirectoryIndex` has index.php with priority over index.html.

Comment: @Laerte this is the content in dir.conf

<IfModule mod_dir.c>
        DirectoryIndex index.html index.cgi index.pl index.php index.xhtml inde$
</IfModule>

Comment: Change to `<IfModule mod_dir.c> DirectoryIndex index.php index.html index.cgi index.pl</IfModule>` and restart apache service `sudo service apache2 restart`.

Comment: @Laerte okay, then should I use .htaccess in "public/admin" location ? Because I have removed it now, kept only "public/.htaccess".

Comment: This dir.conf file is a general configuration for this, so you can have htaccess in your directory, but you don't need to configure DirectoryIndex again in it.

Answer (score 0):

Normal way to check if user is authenticated is [Middleware](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/middleware)

In your case, check-auth runs when you go to: `localhost:8000/admin/` or `localhost:8000/admin/check-auth` othwewise laravel will not check authentication.

Please look at Laravel Middlewares.

Comment: In my case check-auth does not run, I am getting error: The requested resource /admin was not found on this server. This code is just a part of my web.php file and controller.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the best way is using Middleware to check if the logged in user is admin or not.. and it will make your code more elegant than now..
You only need to make the middleware to check if it's admin or not.. if it's admin then return `$next($request)`, if not redirect to other page..
Then change your code..

```
 Route::prefix('admin')->group(function () {
        Route::get('/', 'AdminController@index');
});
```

Then create the admin controller and add index function like

```
public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware('admin');
}

public function index()
{
    return view('adminpage');
}
```